# How do I add PropertyDescriptors to a class rather then override them?

Tags: propertygrid, propertydescriptor, iextenderprovider

If I have a class that implements **ICustomTypeDescriptor** I can override the **GetProperties()** method to completely replace all the properties of the class with my custom **PropertyDescriptors**.

But what if i want to keep the existing properties of the class and append additional properties to the class? Is there a way to return a set of custom property descriptors that get added to the existing class properties?

For example I want the user to be able to define custom properties in my program that will show up in a property grid. The values of the custom properties will be stored in a **Dictionary(string key, object value)** collection, and I want to append **PropertyDescriptors** that will read and write values too and from this collection based on the key values.

I don't think **IExtenderProvider** would work because it only adds the properties of one class to another. But I need to be able to add and remove the properties dynamically at run time. Can I have an **IExtenderProvider** class that also implements **ICustomTypeDescriptor** so that properties it adds can be figured out at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to by just adding to the current collection:

```
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection cols = base.GetProperties(attributes);
        cols.Add(); // Add your custom property descriptor here
        return cols;
    }
```